# React better way to get value

Tags: reactjs

I have this react component and works fine!

```
var SettingsCtrl = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
         return {
             value: 'select'
         }
     },
    changeColor: function(){
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        if (document.getElementById('lang').value !== "select"){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById('lang').value
            localStorage.setItem("color", document.getElementById('lang').value);

        }
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
        <div>
            <select id="lang" onChange={this.changeColor} value={this.state.value}>
                <option value="select">Select</option>
                <option value="lightblue">lightblue</option>
                <option value="lightcoral">lightcoral</option>
                <option value="lightgreen">lightgreen</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(
    <SettingsCtrl />,
    document.getElementById('settingsMenu')
    );
```

My question is if I can change the `document.getElementById('lang').value` with the state value somehow , I try this.state.value but doesnt work...

[here is the gitlab repo](https://gitlab.com/ditsikts/quicknotes/tree/master)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState doesn't change state in sync way.
So then you do:

```
this.setState({value: event.target.value});
```

you can't be sure what the state actualy already changed.

the better decision:

```
changeColor: function(event){      
    if(event.target.value !== 'select') {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = event.target.value
        localStorage.setItem("color", event.target.value);
    }
}
```

in this case you don't need state.value.